type '' does not provide a subscript operator
The problem I have is with printing out spelare1[i] and  the function kopaEnheter.  I been going back and forward for a while so the problem might be else where.  Have looked around for solution but my problem have bounce around between errors. Im new to coding doing a 5 week course.  Been looking for answers, but I might not looking at it right. All i do is moving the problem to something else with in the function or spelare1[i].
I been looking at this for too long so I might done something wild and crazy in my attempts for fixing this problem.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Spelare {
    int guld;
    int soldater;
    int inkomst;
    int mur;
    int hp;
    int soldater_attackera;
    int pris_soldater; // Pris för soldater 5
    int pris_mur;      // Pris för att laga mur 10
    int pris_farm;     // Pris för att bygga gårdar 10
    int nyRunda;
};
struct npc {
    int guldData;
    int soldaterData;
    int inkomstData;
    int murData;
    int hpData;
};
Spelare spelare1 = { 10, 0, 5, 10, 1, 0, 5, 10, 10, 0 };
class spelare1 {
public:
    spelare1();
};
npc data[5];
//------------------------------------------------------------------

void kopaEnheter(struct Spelare &spelinfo, int antal) {

    int totalPris = 5 * antal;
    if (totalPris == spelare1.guld || totalPris <= spelare1.guld) {
        spelare1.guld -= totalPris;
        spelare1.soldater += antal;
        cout << "Du köpte " << antal << " soldater!\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Du har inte tillräckligt med guld för att köpa " << antal << " soldater.\n";
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

bool spel = true, program = true;
int main() {
    while (program == true) {

        int val;
        cin >> val;
        cout << "\n";

        switch (val) {

            program = false;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Ogiltigt val\n";
    
        case 1:
            while (spel == true) {
                string rss[4] { "    | Guld: ", "| Soldater: ", "| Inkomst: ",
                        "| Mur: " };
                cout << "    ---------------------------------------------\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    cout << rss[i] << spelare1[i];
                    cout << "|\n    ---------------------------------------------\n";
                    cout << "1. Köp soldater\n";
                    cout << "2. Laga mur\n";
                    cout << "3. Bygg farm\n";
                    cout << "4. Nästa runda\n";
                    cout << "5. Attackera\n";
                    cout << "6. Avsluta\n";
    
                    int antal;
                    int spelval;
                    cin >> spelval;
    
                    switch (spelval) {
                        case 1: {
        
                            cout << "Ange antal soldater du vill köpa: ";
                            cin >> antal;
                            if (antal == 0)
                                break;
                            else {
                                kopaEnheter(spelare1, antal);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

I have tried changing it up but all i do is walk in circle with repeating errors.  It either let me run the program, but with numbers dont show correctly or print rss wrong or takes numbers from another array thats not linked to user.
some of the errors in the same spot
Expected Unqualified Id Error
No matching function for call
type 'Spelare' does not provide a subscript operator


In this statement cout << rss[i] << spelare1[i]; you are using the subscript operator with an object  of the type Spelare  that is not of an array type due to this declaration Spelare spelare1 = {10, 0, 5, 10, 1, 0, 5, 10, 10, 0}; So it is naturally that the compiler issues an error. What is unclear?

The error says spelare does not provide a subscript operator, and points to this code spelare1[i]. I'm wondering why you think this code is OK? What are you expecting spelare1[i] to do? You clearly have some misunderstanding, but it's hard to know what it is.

At its most basic rss is an array so rss[i] is OK, spelare1 is not an array so spelare1[i] is not OK.

Unrelated: You've made a type called spelare1 and also an instance of Spelare named spelare1. This is going to cause you headache later on if it doesn't already.

@john, Proberly made more of a mess trying to "fix" it on my own.
want to print out in case 1: rrs[i] and the first four  value of the struct for spelare1 and the function to add and remove  value from the spelare1.

@SirGhostToad OK well I don't know about the last part, but for the printing part see my answer.

Taking a wild guess here, but it seem you want to treat spelare1 as if it is an array. But it isn't so the compiler complains. I think what you want is this
Replace
cout << rss[i] << spelare1[i];

with
cout << rss[i];
switch (i)
{
case 0:
    cout << spelare1.guld;
    break;
case 1:
    cout << spelare1.soldater;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << spelare1.inkomst;
    break;
case 3:
    cout << spelare1.mur;
    break;
}

But perhaps better is to remove the for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) loop entirely like this code
cout <<  "    | Guld: " << spelare1.guld << 
    "| Soldater: " << spelare1.soldater <<
    "| Inkomst: " << spelare1.inkomst << 
    "| Mur: " << spelare1.mur;

